# Facebook iOS SDK error when requesting user info

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm working on an iPhone application and part of it relies on Facebook integration. I downloaded version 3.1 of the SDK from the website and followed the first tutorial, found at this link: [Authenticate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/).

I'm using iOS 6.0.1 on an iPhone 4 and Xcode 4.5.

Although the login works fine, when following the steps [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/) in order to request basic user information, the application gives the following error:

```
2013-01-01 23:13:57.966 AppName[8691:907] Error: HTTP status code: 400
2013-01-01 23:13:57.977 AppName[8691:907] FBSDKLog: Response <#1111> <Error>:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

This is the code I'm using to request the information:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                    FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, nil]];

    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *aUser,
                                                           NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken]);
            userProfileImage.profileID = aUser.id;

            self.user = [[User alloc] initWithName:aUser.name andLocation:[aUser.location objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [self.user saveUser];
            [nameTextField setText:[self.user getName]];
            [locationTextField setText:[self.user getLocation]];
        }
    }];
}
```

The weird part is that the FBRequest works in the simulator. I checked the access token and I get one on the iPhone too.

One other thing that might be important: On the simulator the application redirects to the Facebook website where it gets authorized(I can view it in my app list on Facebook). On the other hand, when logging in from the device, I only get a standard alert the first time I login and the app doesn't get added on Facebook.

*P.S.: This is my first question, so I apologize for the amount (or lack) of information. Thank you in advance for helping me out!*

Answer (score 0):

I have been frantically scouring Google for an answer to this for the last couple of days and couldn't find an answer. It was very upsetting, not necessarily because of the bug itself, but because so many people had it, but so few actual answers were given.

The error seems to be a permission issue. If you login from iOS 6, then delete the app from your Facebook, the device will still think you gave the app authorization, thus returning the error. The best answer I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415500/341331).

Today, after I loaded the app on the device again, without trying the simulator first, it worked like a charm. My advice if you have the same issue is to work on some other code for a while and try again the following day. It's not the perfect solution and I think Apple/Facebook should try and fix that, but it works.